# Question about Parseval's theorem

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Parseval's theorem claims:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left| \hat{f}(n) \right|^2 = \|f\|^2$$

Isn't the absolute value redundant, because of the square?

Comment: Absolute value $\not=$ modulus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because $\hat{f}(n) \in \mathbb{C}$ . Therefore $\left(\hat{f}(n)\right)^2 \neq \left|\hat{f}(n)\right|^2 $